Rails: Validation-errors on object are gone after render :new
I have implemented following validation on my model-class:
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }
end

It works fine. It isn't possible anymore to create Department-objects without providing a name.
But in my template there are no errors available.
Error-Messages: <%= @department.errors.full_messages.size %>
<% if @department.errors.any? %>
  <% @department.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
     <h3><%= message %> </h3>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= render "form", department: @department %>

The error-messages debug-output shows always 0.
My controller-code:
   def new
     @department = Department.new
   end

  def create
    @department = Department.create(department_params)

    if @department.save
      puts "-- Positive --"
      redirect_to departments_path
    else
      puts "-- Negative --"
      puts @department
      puts @department.errors.full_messages
      puts "Error message: #{@department.errors.full_messages.size}"
      puts " ------------ "
      render :new
    end
  end

Output:
-- Negative --
#<Department:0x0000000109b59398>
Name can't be blank
Name is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
Error message: 2
 ------------ 

Means: In the controller is everything as expected. But in the view-template errors is empty (size 0).
What goes wrong here? How can it be fixed?

@Alex That did it. Thanks a big bunch. I you want, then turn your comment to an answer. I will accept it.

You should be using @department = Department.new(department_params) and not .create which will insert the record. Rails won't actually do two queries but you're laying a trap for yourself if you want to manipulate the record before saving at a later point.

You have to specify status 422 to let Turbo know that you're rendering an error page, otherwise, it expects a redirect after a form submission:
render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity

You can also see the error message from Turbo in browser console.
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission
